# Stop QTP execution using c#

Tags: c#, qtp

I recently started working on Selenium and QTP. I have been tasked to fulfill a requirement from the testing team to programatically stop QTP using C#. This small implementation is part of a framework that the team wants to put in place.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but according to the documentation, what I am doing should technically work, but it doesn't.

I am able to get the test status etc., but when I try to stop the test, everything goes wrong. QTP stops responding and I fail to even manually stop the test. Below is my code:

**Example 1**

```
QuickTest.Application qtp = new QuickTest.Application();
if (qtp.Test.IsRunning)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test is running"); // works
    qtp.Test.Stop(); // qtp halts and i can't stop execution manually also
}
```

**Example 2**

The same as above, except I try to connect to qtp using the following statement:

```
var app = Marshal.ActivateObject("QuickTest.Application") as QuickTest.Application;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Nobody came up with a solution so far, I don't have one either, but the same behaviour of QTP is common to me. When I perform a test (WinXP, QPT10, web addin) I can't stop or pause it with the stop/pause button. Once I pressed it, QTP hangs and I have to kill the process. The work around I use is putting in a breakpoint (during runtime) on a part I know the codeflow will pass. From the breakpoint, I can pause or stop the test. I do not use C# to interface with QTP, but maybe it has a COM interface method for placing or triggering a breakpoint?

Comment: @AutomatedChaos: thanks for your comments. i am able to pause the test using workarounds but no luck in stopping it. i have asked my team-members to ask HP if this is a known issue. i searched but found nothing. i am also new to c#, qtp so not sure if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Well, if you are new into QTP and C# then you definitly want to read this article [Creating an event interrupt in QTP](http://www.advancedqtp.com/wp-content/uploads/yassa/event-interrupt-in-qtp.pdf). Not _very_ related to your problem, but it is a nice, educational read and maybe it will trigger you to come up with a solution for your actual problem.

Comment: thanks AutomatedChaos. i managed to find a solution. i messaged  relevantcodes.com/contact/ after reading some .net content there and received a class lib with the part i wanted + some other c-style code in c#. not sure what that does though. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about killing the process of QTP, instead of stopping the execution? Does it solve your problem.